# R list class don't work when class attribute is set?

Tags: r, subclass

Some classes in R (list `list()`) don't have a class attribute, but functions list `is` and `inherits` work for them anyway:

```
> x <- list()
> is(x, "list")
[1] TRUE
```

However, this stops working when the class attribute is set:

```
> attr(x, "class")
NULL
> attr(x, "class") <- "myListSubclass"
> x
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "myListSubclass"
> is(x, "list")
[1] FALSE
> inherits(x, "list")
[1] FALSE
```

Setting the class attribute makes these ordinary functions for dealing with classes stop working.

Is there any way to extend a class like `list` in R to get correct behavior? (Maybe include `list` in the class attribute? Or will there be other problems?)

This is also a problem when using `I()`. The resulting list contains the `AsIs` class attribute, so `is`, `inherits` etc. don't work. What's the best solution to this? (Is this a bug?)

Comment: Which object system are you intending to use? S3? S4? Reference classes? R6?

Comment: `structure(list(), class="myListSubclass")`

Comment: @scoa That's probably what you'd do if the goal was to create an S4 class. If the OP only wants to use S3, then appending `"list"` to the class attribute would likely be sufficient. That's why I asked for clarification on which OOP system they are using, as they seem to be mixing terminology from S3/S4.